# How to rearrange poses in Pose Libraries?

Tags: animation

In Blender Pose Library i want to rearrange poses. I would have created poses for lip synk say "a" "e" "i" etc. And later i have a new pose "aaa" a relative of "a" so would like to add it just after "a". How to do that ?

Comment: What ordering do you want to impose upon poses? Do you want to sort them according to lexicographic order?

Comment: As of 29 Aug (r59631) a new feature has been added that will be available in 2.69 - all lists can now be filtered and sorted by name. While it doesn't allow you to manually define the sort order it can make items easy to find.

Answer (score 2):

Technically you can but I will say it's not worth the effort (at least with the current version). This could be an idea for a feature request or a possible addon.

To briefly cover the details for the adventurous, a pose library is nothing more than an action saved for the armature. The pose library name is the action name. The first pose is saved at frame one, the second at frame two and so on. By going to the action editor (dopesheet - action editor context) you can re-arrange the order of the saved poses. This means that the pose names will no-longer match up but you could then rename them to match. Once you start you need to keep track of what frame is for what pose name. If you have 5 poses to re-arrange it's not too hard otherwise it's easier to leave it for now.

Comment: thanks @sambler i am aware of this and as mentioned by you its is tedious. I was thinking if any script way of doing it. Any way i would not do it manually.